# SQL Query: select all rows where [MyVariable] is <= @MyVariable, or where MyVariable is text

Tags: t-sql

Could someone help me with getting the syntax of this SQL query down? Here is what I have so far.

```
SELECT ... WHERE (@MyVariable IS NULL OR [MyVariable] <= (CAST(@MyVariable as NUMERIC)))
```

What I really need is to be able to select all rows where [MyVariable] is <= @MyVariable BUT there are also 2 text selections MyVariable could be in which case it should always select the row. How do you do that without getting a casting error?

Comment: I'm not sure I'm getting your question: what type is the [MyVariable] column in your table?

Comment: It is an nvarchar. The data in that column will always be 1,2,3,4,TEXT1, TEXT2. In the select query the row should be selected if the value in that column is <= @MyVariable OR if the @MyVariable is either text option. Sort of confusing I know.

Comment: You probably should fix your table structure at some point too.  It's a bad sign when you have to convert a string to a numeric value that you have to compare to a null then compare to a variable unless that same string field contains another value...

Comment: @JNK Sorry what? That was sort of hard to follow. The allowable values in the column type were not my choice. It is the format of the data as imported from a client's spreadsheet and also as exported to the screen. Would there be a better way to do this?

Comment: @Novacara - If you have a field you want to use as a numeric, populate it with numbers and use a datatype.  Same with strings.  Having "generic" fields with text and numbers both is generally a bad idea.

Comment: @JNK I totally understand why this is not best practice. As I said before, the data types and columns were not my choice nor under my control.

Comment: @novacara - if you are getting a spreadsheet and importing it to some set of tables where you are then running queries you absolutely have control over it!  Just because you get it that way from your client doesn't mean you have to keep it that way to do the work you are trying to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to do a couple contortions to get it to work.. but i think using ISNUMERIC combined with a case statement will do the trick:

```
SELECT ... WHERE 
@MyVariable IS NULL OR 
ISNUMERIC(@MyVariable) = 0 OR 
[MyVariable] < CASE 
                 WHEN IsNumeric(@MyVariable) = 1 
                     THEN CAST(@MyVariable as NUMERIC) 
                 ELSE 0 -- if you have negatives in your db go to max negative
             END
```

Comment: I will give it a shot and let you know!

Comment: @novacara: you didn't say what DBMS you're using, but note that IsNumeric works for SQL Server but not (AFAIK) for MySQL

Comment: Oh yeah sorry...I am using SQL Server

Comment: @novacara - Also bear in mind `ISNUMERIC` can give what you would consider false positives.  You can google this but for an example see: http://codecorner.galanter.net/2009/04/03/tsql-isnumeric-function-returns-false-positives/